How to terminate/abort the lane change in SUMO?
I found that in SUMO, once traci.vehicle.changeLane("self_car", "{}".format(0), 5) be started, it will not accept new action during the 5 steps, For example, if I want to abort the lane change in this whole duration, what should i do? Here's my code, since it's no use:
def abort_lane_change(egoID, original_lane_index):
    traci.vehicle.changeLane(egoID, original_lane_index, 0) 
    print(f"Vehicle {egoID} aborting lane change and returning to lane {original_lane_index}")


for step in range(duration):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    traci.vehicle.setLaneChangeMode("self_car", 0b000000000000)
    traci.vehicle.setLaneChangeMode("vehicle1", 0b000000000000)
    traci.vehicle.setSpeedMode("self_car", 0)
    traci.vehicle.setSpeedMode("vehicle1", 0)
    traci.simulationStep()

    if step == 10:  # 假设在第10步开始换道
        traci.vehicle.changeLane(egoID, 1, 5)  # 换到车道1，用时5秒

    if 10 < step < 15:  # 在10到15步之间尝试中止换道
        current_lane_index = traci.vehicle.getLaneIndex(egoID)
        print(f"Step {step}: Current lane index of {egoID} is {current_lane_index}")
        if current_lane_index != original_lane_index:
            abort_lane_change(egoID, original_lane_index)

I will really be appreciated if any one can help me with this problem.

It works here. The vehicle is moving to the new lane and right back afterwards. Can you maybe share more code and your SUMO version?

That's not what I want, I want to abort the lane change in the middle of the lc process(eg the whole process is 5 s, and I want the vehicle to abort the lc when the time is 2s). what should I do? plus my sumo version is 1.8. Thank you

Do you use the sublane model or the lanechange.duration option?
